# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.$refs[''] is undefined

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vuejs3, vagrant

Presently, I am attempting to create a PHP laravel app with VueJS 2 (cf. https://www.linkedin.com/learning/laravel-9-0-essential-training) but I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.$refs[''] is undefined
    addProgram http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:39
    promise callback*zh http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    addProgram http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:39
    0 http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:39
    yr http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    on http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    n http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    gr http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    z$ http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    Q$ http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    J http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    M http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    O http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    P http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    J http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    M http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    O http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    re http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    run http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    update http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    pe http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    te http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    ne http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    O http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    P http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    J http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    M http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    O http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    P http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    Y http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    O http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    re http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    run http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    update http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    pe http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    te http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    ne http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    O http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    wt http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    mount http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    mount http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7
    <anonymous> http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:39
app-678b77ff.js:39:11758
GET
http://dev.nadias/images/awah_job_flyer_web.png
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 385ms]

XHRPOST
http://dev.nadias/api/programs/upsert
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 379ms]

Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { stack: "ke@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-

678b77ff.js:5:66034\nDD@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:952\n_@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:4096\nEventHandlerNonNull*UD</<@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:4154\nUD<@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:3222\nG_@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:6595\nrequest@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:10242\nn/<@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:10697\nnE/<@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:5:60773\nsavePrograms@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:39:11808\nRB/t[1]<@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:39:12297\nrb/<@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:99677\nyr@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:29599\non@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:29680\nn@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:87052\nEventListener.handleEvent*gr@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:86416\nz$@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:86622\nQ$@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:87391\nJ@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:66189\nM@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:65835\nO@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:65245\nre@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:69698\nrun@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:20260\npe/T.update@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:69975\npe@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:70001\nte@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:68781\nne@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:68560\nO@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:65274\nP@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:66792\nJ@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:66037\nM@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:65835\nO@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:65245\nP@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:66792\nY@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:68285\nO@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:65203\nre@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:69698\nrun@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:20260\npe/T.update@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:69975\npe@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:70001\nte@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:68781\nne@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:68560\nO@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:65274\nwt@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:73874\nmount@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:57144\ncb/t.mount@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:7:100783\n@http://dev.nadias/build/assets/app-678b77ff.js:39:13167\n", message: "Request failed with status code 500", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: {…} }
```

The issue I think is that I just used the default PHP Laravel. version which uses vite but it appears that this does not have $refs like webpack does in older versions of PHP Laravel.

When I check `~/public/app.js` in a Vue JS 2 application I see these values in `initLifeCycle` which obviously includes the `refs` that I am looking for:

```
  vm.$children = [];
  vm.$refs = {};

  vm._watcher = null;
  vm._inactive = null;
  vm._directInactive = false;
  vm._isMounted = false;
  vm._isDestroyed = false;
  vm._isBeingDestroyed = false;
```

When I check the PHP Laravel Version 10.17.1 which uses Vite I don't see anything like that.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Or should I just switch from using Vite to Webpack / Mix?

Here is the code from the course in `CategoryManager.vue` that is causing the error:

```
        addCategory() {
            this.categories.push({
                id: 0,
                name: '',
                image: '',
                display_order: this.categories.length + 1
            });
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                this.$refs[''][0].focus();
            });
        },
```

FYI here is the source code: https://github.com/john1726/nadias